# Sending data through broken pipe

Tags: python, sockets

When I connect a socket to a server socket, and the server socket at a given time shuts down, I get a `BrokenPipeError` on the client side. But not the next time I try to send something, but the time after that.

Here a SSCCE:

Server:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import socket

s = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind ( ('', 10100) )
s.listen (1)
print ('Waiting on client')
client, _ = s.accept ()
print ('Accepted')
data = b''
done = False
while not done:
    data += client.recv (4096)
    msgs = data.split (b'\r')
    for msg in msgs [:-1]:
        print ('received {}'.format (msg) )
        done = msg == b'exit'
    data = msgs [-1]
s.close ()
print ('Server down')
```

Client:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import socket

s = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ('Connecting')
s.connect ( ('localhost', 10100) )
print ('Connected')
for msg in [b'ping', b'pang', b'exit', b'ping', b'pang']:
    print ('Sending {}'.format (msg) )
    sent = s.send (msg + b'\r')
    print ('Sent {}. {} bytes transmitted'.format (msg, sent) )
    input ('>> ')
```

I start up the server, then the client and hit enter to step through the messages.

The server output is:

```
Waiting on client
Accepted
received b'ping'
received b'pang'
received b'exit'
Server down
```

The client output is:

```
Connecting
Connected
Sending b'ping'
Sent b'ping'. 5 bytes transmitted
>> 
Sending b'pang'
Sent b'pang'. 5 bytes transmitted
>> 
Sending b'exit'
Sent b'exit'. 5 bytes transmitted
>> 
Sending b'ping'
Sent b'ping'. 5 bytes transmitted
>> 
Sending b'pang'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./client.py", line 10, in <module>
    sent = s.send (msg + b'\r')
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Why do I get the `BrokenPipeError` after the last `pang` and not after the `ping`?

Why does `send` return 5 when sending the `ping` after the `exit`?

Why is the pipe not broken immediately after the server is down?

---

EDIT: After having sent `exit`, I don't hit enter on the client console unless the server console has already printed `Server down`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The send function only ensures that the data has been transferred to the socket buffer. When the server closes it sends a FIN,ACK packet to which the client replies only ACK. The socket from client side will not be closed until the client calls the close method itself too. The connection is then "Half-Open".

When the client sends again data to the closed server socket, the server replies with RST to which the client is expected to abort the connection. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-33 on Half-Open Connections and Other Anomalies. However, the socket is closed after the send method has returned. That's why only the next send will crash on BrokenPipe, as the connection is now closed from the client side too.

Comment: This is why I put the `input` in the client. I don't hit enter until on the server console the last receive has been printed. Even so, I get the broken type one send too late. What does the return value of `send` mean? That so many bytes have been handed over to the OS? To my NIC? Or with TCP that they indeed have been received on the other side?

Comment: I tested your code running Wireshark. It seems the FIN,ACK is sent from the server when you call close() on it. However, the client doesn't send back the FIN,ACK as it should, even calling shutdown(SHUT_RDWR). So I guess for the client the connection is still open. When the new data is sent, all bytes are placed in the buffer and the operation succeeds. However, when transmitted the client receives a RST and only then closes its socket. The following send thus fails. The [how to](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket) has interesting infos.

Comment: Edited the answer after having a better look at your problem.